# Simple update field in elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, sense

I started using Elsaticsearch and Sense few weeks ago.
Now I need to bulk update String field in all the documents of certain index as follows:
If the String starts with "+", update the field to same value without the "+".

old: number: "+212112233"
new: number: "212112233"

Is there a simple way for me to do it with the REST DSL or do I need to use Python?

Thanks!

Comment: Python library for ElasticSearch is most probably using REST API too. On topic: afaik you cannot do both query and update in ElasticSearch. Update means reindexing and reindexing is done individually. So you should either keep getting a batch of elements which should be updated and then reindexing them, or if your data comes from the external source, perhaps find the wrong data there and reindex them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can install the [update-by-query plugin](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery), there's a way to do it. That plugin works by giving it a query matching the documents to update and a script to update the matching documents.

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/_update_by_query -d '
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "_source[\"your_field\"].indexOf(\"+\") == 0"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "script": "ctx._source.your_field = ctx._source.your_field.substring(1);"
}'
```

Note: replace `your_index`, `your_type` and `your_field` with respectively your index, type and field name.

So, we tell the plugin to update all documents containing a `your_field` value that starts with `+` (not knowing if `your_field` is an analyzed string or not, here we look directly into the `_source` to make sure we check the raw string value that was indexed) and then we tell the script to update each matching document by taking a substring of the value leaving out the `+` sign.